Policy Improvement Theorem usage issues
In Page 101-102 of Sutton and Barto's Book on RL (2018 edition) where it is desired to prove that $\epsilon$-greedy is an improvement over $\epsilon$-soft policies It is written

Thus, by the policy improvement theorem, $\pi' \geq \pi$ (i.e., $v_{\pi'}(s) \geq v_\pi(s)$, for all $ s \in \mathcal{S} $

The policy improvement theorem as stated in the book is

Let $\pi$ and $\pi'$ be any pair of deterministic policies such that, for all $s \in \mathcal{S}$,
$$q_\pi (s, \pi' (s)) \geq v_\pi (s) \tag{4.7} $$
Then the policy $\pi'$ must be as good as, or better than, $\pi$. That is, it must obtain greater or equal expected return from all states $s \in \mathcal{S}$:
$$v_\pi' (s) \geq v_\pi (s)$$

How did they use policy improvement theorem since the theorem discussed before applies to deterministic policies which is not the case here.

Actually policy improvement theorem (PIT) applies to stochastic policies too since in their book's definition of the action value function (4.6) is defined as $q_{\pi}(s, a) = \mathbb{E}[R_{t+1} + v_{\pi}(S_{t+1}) | S_t =s, A_t =a]$, and in their derivation of PIT below (4.7) they use expectation value w.r.t. the stochasticity of the policy throughout without any assumption of deterministic policies. They just added the unnecessary 'deterministic' qualifier here, potentially confusing readers.
